# Displaying custom String as link in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

How can I show a custom string like `[1234|alink]` as link with "alink" as text and "1234" as its location without replacing it with a `<a>` tag?
I mean something like a BBCode.

Comment: have you tried to play with editor kit(actually you just have to define a custom parser to handle bbcodes)? It should be possible by subclassing/delegating existing HTMLEditorKit and then by calling setEditorKit on jeditorpanel instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several options here:

1. You pre-process your strings and convert your tags to equivalent HTML
2. You start playing with parsers/DTD/[EditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html).

   a. You create your own syntax (could be time-consuming)

   b. You reuse the [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) (you need to extend it), try to add more information to the default DTD to add your custom elements (and therefore make the Parser return your additional elements) and you extend the ViewFactory so that you can render your new elements with dedicated views.

While option 2. is clearly better in the long run (and particularly if you are really interested in high performance), option 1. is really easy to implement.

See these links for more info:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/DTD.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/ParserDelegator.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/DocumentParser.html